# Error during installing scrapy in mac

Tags: python, scrapy

While I am trying to install scrapy on my Mac Os :

```
pip install Scrapy
```

I get an error

> Uninstalling zope.interface-4.1.1:
>       Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/**init**.py',
>   '/private/var/folders/h6/sh206j3129l3bvkbccnqp3xm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-I2xi1I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/**init**.py',
>   "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted:
>   '/private/var/folders/h6/sh206j3129l3bvkbccnqp3xm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-I2xi1I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/**init**.py'"),
>   ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/zope/**init**.pyc',
>   '/private/var/folders/h6/sh206j3129l3bvkbccnqp3xm0000gn/T/pip-uninstall-......]

Comment: `pip install scrapy --user`?

Comment: i entered this command , i don't see the error anymore ,However the scrapy is not installed yet :
 scrapy startproject 
-bash: scrapy: command not found

Comment: scrapy: command not found

Comment: and sudo install scrappy result is :
The directory '/Users/zahra/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/zahra/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.

Comment: Do not invoke `sudo`, it won't bring you anything. The only issue left is to determine the correct path to the scrapy binary. Run `pip show -f scrapy | grep Location` and `pip show -f scrapy | grep bin/scrapy`, what do you get?

Comment: ZZ-net:~ zahra$ pip show -f scrapy | grep Location
Location: /Users/zahra/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
ZZ-net:~ zahra$ pip show -f scrapy | grep bin/scrapy
  ../../../bin/scrapy

Comment: Ok, so `/Users/zahra/Library/Python/2.7/bin/scrapy ...` should work; to be able to call `scrapy` without the full path, open the file `.bash_profile` in your home directory and add two lines at the bottom: first is `PATH=${PATH}:${HOME}/Library/Python/2.7/bin` and the second is `export PATH`. Restart the terminal and you're good to go.

Comment: yes!!! the problem solved! thank you so much :)

Comment: Glad I could help! :-)

Comment: still does not work :((

Comment: when i run scrapy says :
ImportError: No module named _util

Comment: What does `pip show pyopenssl | grep Version` return?

Comment: Version: 0.13.1
Location: /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python

Comment: Remove the old one installed: `sudo pip uninstall -y pyopenssl`, then reinstall as user: `pip install --user pyopenssl`.

Comment: Cannot uninstall 'pyOpenSSL'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to it which would lead to only a partial uninstall.

Comment: Hmm, that's not good (btw why do you have `pyopenssl` installed system-wide anyway?), but should be avoidable by installing a local copy: try `pip install --user "pyopenssl==18.0.0"` and then running scrapy again.

Comment: oh it was recommended on tutorial of scrappy!! :|  it seems it works in this step! thank you for answering my questions, i guess there would be some other questions in next steps..... :)

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask while it's still not running properly! Unfortunately, I'm no expert in `scrapy` particularly, so if you need help with the code, you will have more luck asking another question...

Answer (score 0):

**Try:**

```
sudo pip install Scrapy --upgrade --ignore-installed
```